# Is there a way to override the default sorting behavior in JQGrid?

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid 4.4.0 and I would like to override the default behavior for how integers are sorted. I can achieve this by setting the `sorttype` property of each `colModel` to a function  instead of the literal `'int'`.

I'd like to know, though, is there a way that I can make this a global change to my JQGrid configuration, as the [example here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions#setting_options_globally) shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use `template` property of `colModel` or the usage of `cmTemplate` option of jqGrid to define default `sorttype` property for all columns of the grid. If you would set `cmTemplate` option in `$.jgrid.defaults` you will change the default `sorttype` property for all columns of all grids:

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    cmTemplate: {
        sorttype: 'int' // you can use functions in the same way
                        // to define custom sorting
                        // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935
                        // for the code example
    }
});
```

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details. For example if you want to define custom sorting like function from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935)

Comment: @TheDavester: You are welcome! I recommend you to use `cmTemplate` and `template`. The options can reduce the code and make it more readable and better manageable.