# Customize sorttype function doesn't work correctly in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

My jqGrid contains a special column whose value is generated by another value, like the Duration Span column, its real value is in seconds like 3690s, and I should transform it to a formmatted string 'Hour : Minute : Second', in this cause it is '1:1:30'. Now, I want to it works well in sortting, so I write a customize function to handle this:

1, Following code fragment is column definition:

```
{
    name : 'time',
    index : 'time',
    align: 'center',
    width :  '12%',
    sorttype : sortTimeFuc
}
```

2, Following code fragment is sort function:

```
var sortTimeFuc = (function(cell) {
    var a = cell.split(':');
    var value = parseInt(a[2]) + parseInt(a[1]) * 60 + parseInt(a[0]) * 3600;
    return value;
});
```

But it work incorrectly as below:

[image]

Can anybody gives me help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you make some errors. First of all you should remove parentheses over the function. Unneeded parentheses can follow to invocation of the function. The second and the most important error which I see in your code is the usage of [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) without the second parameter 10. The last error is the usage of `width :  '12%'`. jqGrid don't support '%' inside of width. Instead of that you can use just `width: 12` and specify `width` of the total grid or use `autowidth: true`. Because the option `shrinkToFit: true` is default option if will follow to scaling the width of the columns based on the total width of jqGrid and `width` property of the column, which will define the proportion between the columns.

So the resulting code could be as the following

```js
{
    name: 'time',
    align: 'center',
    width: 12,
    sorttype: function (cell) {
        var a = cell.split(':');
        return parseInt(a[2], 10) + parseInt(a[1], 10) * 60 +
            parseInt(a[0], 10) * 3600;
    }
}
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) as an example of very close implementation of custom sorting.

Comment: Thanks all the same. I firgue it out in other way.

Comment: @BradyChu: You are welcome! Next time you should better invest more your time before posting new question. You spend time of other people by posting unneeded questions.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, your suggestion is good that I will take a serious thinking before I post any question on this platform.

Comment: @BradyChu: I think that in your case the usage of no `sorttype` which means `sorttype: "text"` is the best choice.

Comment: Thanks! 'text' is sort type by default.

Answer (score 0):

Because the merged time string meet the sortting condition of string, so just set the sorttype of this column to 'text'. Problem solved.