# Custom Sorting on JqGrid Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid with grouping.
I am having Grouped Data something like this.

```
Test0001
     name description date response
                      date response

Test00011
     name Description date response
                      date response
                      date response
Test0002
     name Description date rersponse
```

I want to sort group header, currently it has been sort as a sting, but I want to remove prefix and then I want to sort it as int.
**So output would be first Test0001 ,Test0002 then Test00011.**
So is there any way to add custom sort on groups

Comment: Do you use *client side* sorting, server side sorting or mixed (in case of remote `datatype` and `loadonce: true`)? Which `datatype` you use? If you use *client side* grouping then jqGrid makes sorting of the column with `Test0001`, `Test0002`, `Test00011`. In the case you can define `sorttype` as function to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use *client side sorting* then you can solve the problem by adding `sorttype` defined as function. It allows to replace original data of the column to another one during sorting only. For example you can parse input value of `sorttype` in two parts, convert the second part to integer and construct another **normalized** string which you return from `sorttype`. It's enough that `Test0001`, `Test0002`, `Test00011` will be converted to `Test0001`, `Test0002`, `Test0011` (the last item contains less `0` characters before `11`). See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) for the code example.