# How do i sort a column that has multiple types of values? [Trirand JQGrid 4.6]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i have used q jqgrid, '**groupd header row config**' version of jqgrid in the [demo website](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

[image]

it generates the grid. but assume the the senario where  `Notes` column can contains numbers and string as in some rows there are numbers an in some rows there are string chars, sorting truns off and it only works for strings chars.

scenario:Assume the table has five rows and `Notes` column has the following data in five rows:

```
this is good

123

number 123 number

>123.23

<=222.88
```

i have added the sorting option to colModel ussing sort:true but this only sorts if the notes column has string chars for all the rows but does not if it has a conbination of number rows and string char rows. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid contains multiple possibilities to customize the sorting. First of all it's important to mention that all the below possibilities have sense only if you use `datatype: "local"` or some remote `datatype` (`"json"`, `"jsonp"`, `"xml"`) in combination with `loadonce: true`. In the last case the `datatype` will be changed to the `"local"` after the first loading of data from the server.

To sort the local data in the column jqGrid have to compare the values. It does some preliminary steps. First of all if fills the array with items, which maps the content from one column to the rowid. Thus you can define

```
sorttype: function (cellValue, item) {
    return cellValue; // another value as cellValue can be returned
}
```

It gives you the first way of custom sorting. You can for example use RegEx to extract the "number"-part of the information from the `callValue` and to return it from `sorttype` (which you can define in `colModel` for the column `notes`). See [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomSorttype2.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) for more details.

The second way: defining of `sortfunc` callback in `colModel`. The callback has the prototype

```
sortfunc: function (a, b, direction) {
    // should return 0, 1 or -1
}
```

in old versions of jqGrid and

```
sortfunc: function (a, b, direction, aItem, bItem) {
    // should return 0, 1 or -1
}
```

in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). The `sortfunc` allows you to implement any custom sorting behavior which you need. See [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zkvwoj31/1/) created for [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/192) for the code example.