# JqGrid custom local sorting function (without sorttype)

Tags: javascript, sorting, jqgrid, local

I need to make a custom sort on my grid but my need is not completed by sorttype option.
What I want to do is to keep all empty rows at the first place, and sort other rows in ascending or descending order.
My problem with sorttype is that I can't define a value that will be first in ascending AND descending sortorder.

What I need is the same as JS native sort function but with jqgrid data :

```js
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  var result = 0

  if (a>b) {
    result = 1; // Exchange a & b value
  }
  else {
    result = -1; // Keep a before b
  }
  
  if (b == "") {
    result = 1; // Exchange a & b value -> Put "" value always first !
  }


  return result;
});
```

Is there something like that in jqgrid functionalities ?

Comment: First of all you should specify which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Free jqGrid allows to specify `sortfunc` callback function with parameters `(a, b, direction, aItem, bItem)`, where `direction` is 1 or -1 depend on the sort oder, `a` and `b` represents the values from the sorting column and `aItem` and `bItem` represents full local data of compared rows. It allows to make any custom sorting order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I never hear about sortfunc, it's very usefull ! But I'm using 4.6 version of Free jqGrid, so I thinks that's why I don't have "aItem" and "bItem" parameters ? Is there any solution to get that informations in version 4.6 ? It could allows me to make a better sorting.

Comment: The callback `sortfunc` with `(a, b, direction)` parameters exists already in jqGrid 4.6. Nevertheless jqGrid 4.6 is 4 years old. It's dead and isn't supported since a long time. The last version of "jqGrid" is 4.7. After that there are two main forks of the product: "free jqGrid", which I develop and which can be used for free under the same license as jqGrid 4.6, and *commertial* "Guriddo jqGrid". I recommend you to upgrade to one from two current versions.

Comment: Yes, sortfunc with (a, b, direction) parameters works perfectly :) I'll try to updgrade my jqgrid version to support new parameters. Are there some incompatibility between 4.6 and 4.7 versions ? Or can I change my version without modify anything in existing scripts ? And last question: I found "Guriddo jqGrid" download but not the free 4.7 jqGrid version. Where could I found download link ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: The current version of free jqGrid, which I develop, is 4.15.2. You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [bower](https://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) or [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid), but recommended way is loading from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). See [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for examples

Comment: I repeat once more: jqGrid is dead. Upgrade from 4.6 to 4.7 bring nothing. You should decide *which currently developing fork* you want use and upgrade to it. I try to hold in "free jqGrid" fork to hold maximal upwards compatibility. In the most cases one can replace URLs to jqGrid files and the code will work. To use new features one need to make more changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are exist alternative to `sorttype`: the callback function `sortfunc`, which can be defined in `colModel` instead of `sorttype`. The callback `sortfunc` has 3 parameters `(a, b, direction)` in old versions of jqGrid and 5 parameters `(a, b, direction, aItem, bItem)` in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog1.htm) as an example of usage `sortfunc` and [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40201448/315935) for additional information).